# Is it possible to check if a directory is empty in Swift 2.1?

Tags: xcode, swift

For example I'd like to check if: Users/username/Desktop/folder is empty, or better check if it has files with an .png extension?

I'm really new at all this but if anyone knows please help me :)

Comment: Just select Desktop folder instead of Documents, filter png files and check if !isEmpty

Comment: Keep in mind that Swift leverages Cocoa and CocoaTouch to provide access to a wealth of features on OS X and iOS. This includes the `NSFileManager` class used in the answers below. Those frameworks predate Swift by many years, so in many cases you, will find a lot more resources by searching for Cocoa instead of Swift. Good luck!

Comment: @Doni if you would like to get that folder URL programatically instead of hard coding it you can do like this: guard let desktopFolderUrl =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DesktopDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("folder") else { return }

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks now how to implement it to that previous code from @codedifferent? Sorry but again I'm really new. Thanks for the help guys and merry christmas :)

Comment: if you are gonna put it inside a method or inside viedDidLoad

Comment: guard let dropIconsHereURL =  NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.DesktopDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Drop Icons Here") else { return }

Comment: if you need to use its path you can access dropIconsHereURL.path! or

Comment: guard let dropIconsHerePath =  NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.DesktopDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Drop Icons Here").path else { return }

Answer (score 5):

Use `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath` to get the list of all files in a directoly, then filter the array for `.png` files

```
let path = "/Users/username/Desktop/folder"
do {
    let contents = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(path)
    let images = contents.filter { $0.lowercaseString.hasSuffix(".png") }
} catch let error as NSError {
    // Directory not exist, no permission, etc.
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Ah, nice with filter, plus1

Comment: @dfri thanks, killing some time before my Christmas party

Comment: What better way to kill time than code, right! Happy christmas *<:)

Comment: @CodeDifferent  
I'm using this: "/Users/" + "(username)" + "/Desktop/Drop Icons Here/" but it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let folderPath = "/Users/username/Desktop/folder"

if let contentEnumerator:NSDirectoryEnumerator = fileManager.enumeratorAtPath(folderPath) {
    var numFilesWithSuffix = 0
    let mySuffix = "png"
    while let fileOrFolder = contentEnumerator.nextObject() as? String {
        if fileOrFolder.hasSuffix(mySuffix) {
            numFilesWithSuffix += 1 // count occurences
        }
    }
}
```